# Winapi CreateDC hangs on Win 8

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, windows-8

I have a program which uses winapi functions. When it runs on WinXP (32bit) or Win7 (64bit) everything is OK. But on Win8 (64bit) there is a bug: sometimes program hangs on this code line

```
HDC hDisplay = CreateDC("DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

What might be the reason of it?

p.s. It is built in MSVC 2005 on WinXP 32 bit for platform Win32.

Comment: It *hangs*? As in completely stops executing? Have you tried breaking in with a debugger and single-stepping through the code?

Comment: Also, the code is suspicious because you're using a narrow string literal. Even back in the Windows XP days, everything was Unicode. You should be using `L"DISPLAY"` (or at least one of the macros that handles conversion automatically, like `TEXT("DISPLAY")`).

Comment: The problem might be elsewhere and only manifest on that line. Try a debugger I would also say...

Comment: Works fine here. Unless you give a repro, will be hard to solve.

Comment: This is an environmental problem.  The video driver is the primary suspect.  Not untypical for new Windows releases.

Comment: Cody Gray. Yes, it is completely stops executing, and it is still in process list. Now I think I should try to rebuild program for x64 platform.

Comment: I don't think the bitness is a relevant factor here. Hans's suggestion is a better one: try switching/updating the video driver.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CreateDC(TEXT("DISPLAY"),NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

Comment: If this were the problem, he should be getting a compile-time error about mismatched string literals. He'd have to be forcing the code through with an explicit cast that he's curiously omitted from the question. However, I agree that he should be using Unicode everywhere, even if this doesn't explain the hang.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to rebuild program for 64bit platform, and it works now.

Comment: This does not answer the question you asked

Answer (score 0):

While this question is very old, we're encountering a similar issue today.

We have code that is attempting to Query Printers in this Manner:

```c
hdc = CreateDC(pi->pDriverName, pi->pPrinterName, pi->pPortName, NULL);
```

Where `pi` is a `PRINTER_INFO_2` structure (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/printer-info-2).

It seems like after installing Microsoft KB4517298 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517298/windows-8-1-update-kb4517298) on our Server 2012R2 boxes this line hangs for no apparent reason. Rebuilding the Application in 64bits appears to fix it as it did for the original poster. However we're still at a loss as to why this occurs. Removing the hotfix resolves the issue and reapplying it causes it again.

We're working with our vendor to see if we can get some type of visibility as to why this recent Windows Update broke us (and even better how to fix it!).

Comment: The like doesn't have this issue listed under known issues. You should submit a ticker to Microsoft: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020188/technical-support-for-microsoft-partners

Comment: @vbguyny We opened a support case with them. The root cause is that KB4517298 if installed standalone without any of the previous security rollups introduces a race condition with LPC (Local Procedure Call) the issue can be reproduced by opening up the 32bit version of Notepad and attempting to print.

Comment: From Microsoft Premier Support: "All updates are supposed to be cumulative.  Thus, KB4517298 and KB4512489 are supposed to be a superset of KB4507457, but due to a packaging problem, they are not.  Splwow64.exe was updated in KB4507457 and KB4507448, so installing any KB from those or newer except KB4517298 and KB4512489 will install the updated splwow64.exe.  Running Window Update should also install a missing update from the list to resolve the issue."