# Sending object array to variant works before August 2019 Windows update, but fails after update

Tags: excel, vba

Running the subroutine RunMe works before August 2019 Windows update.

Running the subroutine RunMe fails after August 2019 Windows update. It reports the following error message: "Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)"

```
Public Sub RunMe()
  Dim wksTestArray() As Worksheet
  MsgBox SendArrayToFunction(wksTestArray())
End Sub

Public Function SendArrayToFunction(ByVal vntArray As Variant) As Boolean
  SendArrayToFunction = True
End Function
```

Please note: The error only occurs for an unallocated array.

It can be useful for a function to accept a Variant, which can be either an Array of values, or an Array of objects, for example, IsArrayAllocated is an example function where this would be required.

Is there a fix?

Comment: I'm very curious about whether Word and the rest of Office breaks in the same way.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing too :( VB6 apps also break. BTW, I think this is a problem with the August 2019 Windows update, rather than a problem with an Office update. At least uninstalling KB4512501 fixes the problem for me.

Comment: I reported this breaking change to MS via the Feedback Hub: https://aka.ms/AA5uz8p

Answer (score 6):

The update affects VB6, VBA (including all versions of Office) as well as VBScript!

Microsoft is currently looking into the issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512488/windows-8-1-update-kb4512488 (look at the last row under the section entitled "Known issues in this update")

**Update:**

Microsoft just released a patch for this issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517298/windows-8-1-update-kb4517298

Comment: I also received this error after I got this update when I tried creating an empty array by calling the Array() function in VBA with no arguments.  Uninstalling the update made this problem go away.

Comment: @BenSiron There is a workaround for creating empty arrays https://stackoverflow.com/a/57540873/9439330

Comment: @ComputerVersteher confirmed the workaround works as an alternative to calling Array().  Though I still had to uninstall the update because I also use functions with ParamArray parameters which I was calling with zero arguments.  I also had trouble figuring out how to install KB4517298 on Windows 10.

Comment: Installing KB4517298 fixes this issue for us; but triggers this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312657/winapi-createdc-hangs-on-win-8/57630317#57630317 which is not good.

Comment: I've been watching https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#629msgdesc and saw that Microsoft recently released KB4512941 to fix this issue on 8/30.  I installed KB4512508 thru windows update as before, restarted, then checked for updates again.  KB4512941 showed up, I then installed that which took 15 minutes and a restart.  The problem no longer occurs.  (I'm running Windows 10)

Answer (score 2):

To fix, change the ByVal to ByRef in the function:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
  Dim wksTestArray() As Worksheet
  MsgBox SendArrayToFunction(wksTestArray())
End Sub

Public Function SendArrayToFunction(ByRef vntArray As Variant) As Boolean
  SendArrayToFunction = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 version 1709, this issue has been corrected with this update:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512494/windows-10-update-kb4512494

Comment: Currently this patch seems to be only for Windows 10 version **1709**.

Comment: Yes, each version a specific patch. The next patches should follow soon.

Comment: Meanwhile there are some more patches for different Windows 10 versions.