# Run Time Error 5 when initializing a 2D array

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, runtime-error

I have been initializing a 2D array using `Arr=Array(Array(),Array())`.

But I have found that a Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument would be triggered.

The code have been used for years and the problem arose yesterday so I think it may be the result of some of the updates for MS Office or Windows.

**Update: The Error exists for Windows 10, Windows 7 but NOT for Windows Vista.**

To reproduce the Error:

```
Sub foo()
  Dim Arr As Variant
  Arr = Array(Array(), Array())
End Sub
```

Comment: No repro, but this seems like a very weird way to create an array. Why not `Dim` and then `ReDim`?

Comment: I think that is a convenient and flexible way to declare a dynamic 2D array. Maybe it is not the proper way.

Comment: @BigBen `ReDim` works well with single-dimensional arrays, but not so nicely with 2D ones. I'm questioning the use of an array over, say, a `Recordset`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon that is a good point about 2D arrays. But yes... not sure what OP actually wants to do.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497723/1188513

Comment: Tested code and runs without error. Windows 10 Home version 1903 Access 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to a bug discovered in the security update that was pushed by Microsoft on 8/13/2019 (https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2019-1182)

Look for the KB number related to your version of Windows and type (32/64 bit) and uninstall the update.  This will fix the issue.

Microsoft is looking into fixing the bug in the update.

**Update**

Microsoft just released a patch: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517298/windows-8-1-update-kb4517298

Answer (score 0):

There is a [workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/de.comp.lang.vbclassic/gx2dTN_XWjE) for creating empty arrays.

You can use the [SafeArrayCreateVector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oleauto/nf-oleauto-safearraycreatevector) API-Function

```vb
Private Declare Function EmptyVariantArr Lib "oleaut32" _
  Alias "SafeArrayCreateVector" (Optional ByVal VT As VbVarType = vbVariant, _
  Optional ByVal LB& = 0, Optional ByVal cElements& = 0) As Variant() 

Dim A()
A() = EmptyVariantArr
```