# Inline OnAction code doesn't work in vba commandbar

Tags: excel, vba, inline, commandbutton, msgbox

I used to have this knowledge: one doesn't have to put a procedure name in the `OnAction` parameter of a button, you could write a function name like this

```
 .OnAction = "=MsgBox(""You pressed a toolbar button!"")"
```

the links below also suggest the same:

[whole example](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/calling-procedure-from-onaction.3617016/)

[the first paragraph](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Application/CreatingaToolbaranddisplayMsgBoxinitsaction.htm)

But now, I can't create code like this, it throws the error:

> sorry, we couldn't find . is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted.

Is this no longer a valid approach?

Comment: *Might* be related to the August update, which is [known to have broken VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497723/1188513) that had been working for years without problems. That said... IMO inlining the `OnAction` like this feels like a hack anyway, puts executable code in a string literal (no compile-time validation), and simply feels downright lazy. What's wrong with setting `OnAction` to an actual procedure that can be easily debugged and extended?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you have KB4512501 installed?

Comment: Perhaps the first "=" is not necessary? You are calling a VBA method, not an Excel function.

Comment: @AJD reading the linked examples it looks like the OP can be taken at face value - this apparently used to work, and no longer does. TBH I think it's a very good thing it no longer works (see above), but I agree it's not cool when something suddenly stops working after years just sitting there collecting dust.

Comment: i am updated for both windows and office. i use office 365 home at home and office 2016 professional at work. neither of them could get it work. i couldn't find any announcement though if it was discouraged anymore, which is a shame. i believe. by the way, nothing wrong with just using normal procedure calls, but i have an excel tutorial site which i mentiona inline onaction. Anyway, i think it's gone for good, thanks everyone