# Has the behavior of the Array() function changed?

Tags: vb6

I have a problem in some old VB6 code which appears to be related to creating an empty array by calling the Array() function with an empty parameter list.

The [help for VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/array-function) indicates that this is legal operation:

> The required arglist argument is a comma-delimited list of values that
>   are assigned to the elements of the array contained within the
>   Variant. If no arguments are specified, an array of zero length is
>   created.

The bones of the function which causes the error are shown below.

The function creates an empty array, adds zero or more elements to the array, and then returns it to the caller.
In this specfic case, it does not add any elements to the array, and therefore tries to return an empty array.

```
Private Function GetActiveRestrictionArray(ByVal Restrictions As String) As Variant

  Dim Result As Variant

  Result = Array()

  'Do some stuff which might call "Redim"
  'but in this case does not.

  GetActiveRestrictionArray = Result

End Function
```

The line GetActiveRestrictionArray = Result is now generating the error **'Invalid procedure call or argument'**.

A user has reported that this error occurs under Windows 10 after performing a Windows update. The same user has reported, that if he reverts this update, then the error disappears. I don't know exactly what update that was.

However, I can now generate the same error in VB6 on a Virtual Machine running Windows 7.

In fact, immediately after the line Result = Array(), if I hold the mouse over the variable Result, it shows the message 'Invalid procedure call or argument' as a tooltip (in this case in German).

[image]

Honestly, I don't know how this code ever worked, but apparently it did.

Is it possible that the behavior of the VB6 Array() function has changed, specifically when it is called with an empty argument list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably caused by the August 2019 patch from Microsoft.  MS has issued some additional updates that addresses this on some of the versions of Windows.

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#629msgdesc

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512508/windows-10-update-kb4512508

https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-US/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2019-1182

Subsequent updates:

Windows 7 x64: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517297/windows-7-update-kb4517297

Windows 10 version 1709: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512494/windows-10-update-kb4512494

Windows 10 version 1809:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4512534

Comment: KB4512941 fixed this for me, available thru windows update as of yesterday, takes 15 minutes and a restart - see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497723/sending-object-array-to-variant-works-before-august-2019-windows-update-but-fai/57503661?noredirect=1#comment101545929_57503661