# What can cause errors other than code? VBA

Tags: vba, hardware

I've got somehow untypical question - what can be other causes to show random errors (e.g 91, 1004, 1001, etc.) in VBA other than wrongly written code?

Because there is such a situation that the same code works on my computer and my excel (so I assume its written properly) and doesn't on my friend's. It's also much much slower in execution (~5x) and in the end it always shows an error, usually 91 (Object variable not set). When adding "On Error Resume Next" the code goes through, however there are mistakes in the results. Closing all other programs doesn't help either.

On my PC I don't have any problems, everything goes fast and smooth, there are no mistakes in the results.

We both have 8gb RAM, I've got Intel i5 (friends got older i3) and different versions of Excel (I've got 16, he's got 13). However, I've tried the code on other computer with Excel 13 and there was no problem at all.

So, the situation is quite weird, have you ever encountered and solved such? What could be the cause?

Comment: It is [always](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/) [*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57497723/11683) the incorrectly written code. It's just that its incorrectness may be less obvious, which often deals with incorrect assumptions about the environment (certain libraries installed, certain date/time handling rules in the locale, certain file paths hardcoded etc).

Comment: I've had the occasion (in my case dealing with code created pivot charts) where different versions of excel would cause issues and I had to add a check in the code for the excel version and determine how to continue processing according to the excel version

Comment: GSerg - Yeah, I mean, I thought the same :D The references/libraries are the same (but even if not - the macro don't use any special ones), date/time handling is the same, filepaths are ok ;/ Glenn G - as said in my original post - excel version is probably not a case (it worked on other machine with older excel)

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
Option Explicit
```

when set does not allow you for no variable declaration.

Also check if references (Tools/References) are the same, if not macro may not working.
If macro is working long (big input data/files etc) errors may cause clicking or writing during the macro (for example in internet browser).

That's from my experience.

Comment: Of course, I always use Option Explicit. And yeah, I already checked references, they're the same. Same with actions while macro is running, doesn't matter ;/